# Why is box-sizing acting different on table vs div?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jC8DL/1/

```
<div style='width:300px;border:1px solid green'>
  <div>Outer div</div>
  <div style='width:100%;border:1px solid red;margin:10px;'>
    Inner div, 10px margin.
  </div>
  <div style='width:100%;border:1px solid red;padding:10px;'>
    Inner div, 10px padding.
  </div>
  <div style='width:100%;border:1px solid red;padding:10px;box-sizing:border-box'>
    Same, with box-sizing: border-box
  </div>
  <table style='width:100%;border:1px solid red;padding:10px;'>
    <tr><td>Inner table, 10px padding</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And it looks like this in my Chrome:

[image]

I think I understand everything until the last one. My Chrome inspector shows the table's computed `box-sizing` style is `content-box` so I expect it to behave like the second div, and overflow and look ugly. Why is it different? Is this documented somewhere in the HTML/CSS spec?

Comment: It's because `div`'s are block elements. Try adding `display: block;` to the inner table. It will display the same as the div would.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: 1) That's just [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) then. 2) The whole point of this question is to ask why a table would behave differently from a block; what would changing the table into a block accomplish?

Comment: @BoltClock You have misinterpreted my comment (it is, hence, a *comment*). I was explaining in short why this difference occurs. I didn't try to answer the question; I didn't post it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, CSS2.1 states the following for tables with the [separated borders model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#separated-borders):

> However, in HTML and XHTML1, the width of the <table> element is the distance from the left border edge to the right border edge.
>
> **Note:** In CSS3 this peculiar requirement will be defined in terms of UA style sheet rules and the 'box-sizing' property.

The current CSS3 definition of [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) does not say anything about this, but translating the above quote it basically means in (X)HTML, tables use the border-box model: padding and borders do not add to the specified width of a table.

Note that in terms of the `box-sizing` property, different browsers seem to handle this special case differently:

- **Chrome**
  `box-sizing` is set to the initial value, `content-box`; changing it has no effect whatsoever. Neither does redeclaring `box-sizing: content-box` within the inline styles, but that should be expected. Either way, Chrome appears to be forcing the table to always use the border-box model.
- **IE**
  `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`; changing it to `content-box` causes it to behave like the second `div`.
- **Firefox**
  `-moz-box-sizing` is set to `border-box`; changing it to `content-box` or `padding-box` causes it to resize accordingly.

Since CSS3 does not yet make any mention of table box sizing, this should not come as a surprise. At the very least, the result is the same — it's only the underlying implementation that's different. But given what the note says above, I would say that IE and Firefox are closer to the intended CSS3 definition, since in Chrome you can't seem to change a table's box model using the `box-sizing` property.

---

Tables with the [collapsing border model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#collapsing-borders) don't have padding at all, although in this case it's not relevant since your table does not use this model:

> Note that in this model, the width of the table includes half the table border. Also, in this model, a table does not have padding (but does have margins).

Answer (score 5):

That's how `<table>` `<td>` `<th>` elements works. These elements are not block level elements.

It contains padding inside the given width like the `box-sizing:border-box` would do on other block level elements.

FYI, I didn't find it anywhere document.