# Inconsistent, half-pixel offset on identical HTML elements in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, frontend

## **Context**

I am working on a website using ASP.NET Core and Bootstrap 3, and I'm running into an issue that completely stumps me.  I've been banging my head on this for about an hour and a half and finally decided I needed to get some expert advice.

The problem I am facing is the inconsistent display of (what should be) identical HTML elements.

[image]

Do you see that teeny-tiny offset?  It's on that middle card, but not the other two.  The difference between that element is half a pixel These small errors are littered throughout the entire list of results, despite the fact that the HTML is identical (since they are generated by a foreach-loop).  Note that the tops of the elements are consistent, so it's actually the height that's different.

To make matters even more interesting, it doesn't happen on every card, and it's only showing up in Firefox.  (Tested on Chrome, EdgeI've been trying to identify a pattern to troubleshoot, but so far I'm stuck.

## **Code**

These Game Result cards are made up of:

1. A parent div for borders/margins
2. And three child elements:

   -The allied result (score and name on the left)

   -The spacer (made using [CSS triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/))

   -The enemy result (score and name on the right)

For the [code itself](https://github.com/C-Kennelly/SpartanClashCore/blob/c594e5cbbe96dd0ef1a18d01325b50ae94baae83/SpartanClash/Components/ServiceRecord/Views/CompanyCards.cshtml), There's a foreach loop that iterates through each game result in the ViewModel, and executes this for each one:

```
@if (battle.GetTeam() == 1)
{
  <div class="game-result-card" id="accordion">
     <div class="team-result team-result-ally team-result-red">
        <h2>@battle.score</h2>
        <h3>@battle.primaryCompany</h3>
     </div>
    <div class="game-result-spacer-red-active"></div>
     <div class="team-result team-result-enemy team-result-blue">
        <h2>@battle.enemyScore</h2>
        <h3>@battle.enemyHeader</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
 }
else
{
    <div class="game-result-card" id="accordion">
        <div class="team-result team-result-ally team-result-blue">
            <h2>@battle.score</h2>
            <h3>@battle.primaryCompany</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="game-result-spacer-blue-active"></div>
        <div class="team-result team-result-enemy team-result-red">
            <h2>@battle.enemyScore</h2>
            <h3>@battle.enemyHeader</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

So basically, the "if" just decides if it's a red card or a blue card on the left.  Finally, I've got the following [CSS elements applied](https://github.com/C-Kennelly/SpartanClashCore/blob/c594e5cbbe96dd0ef1a18d01325b50ae94baae83/SpartanClash/wwwroot/css/game-result-card.css) (beyond anything included in Bootstrap.)

```
.body-content {
max-width: 600px;
align-items: center;
}

...(removed extraneous things)...

.game-result-card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    height: 116px;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333333;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.team-result {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 110px;
    width: 40%;
    border: 0;
}

.team-result h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.team-result h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.team-result-red {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: firebrick;
}

.team-result-blue {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}


.game-result-spacer-red-active {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 110px solid darkslateblue;
    border-left: 110px solid firebrick;
}

.game-result-spacer-blue-active {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 110px solid firebrick;
    border-left: 110px solid darkslateblue;
}
```

## **What I've Tried So Far**

The main solutions I looked into were tweaking the pixel widths on the elements to see if different values affected it, or if using % based width fixed it.  No beans there.

I also tried using Firefox's Inspector (F12 menu) to verify that elements were the same size (height and width).  They were.

I also tried using the F12 menu to edit the elements so that they had identical content - theory was that the text width would cause a slight increase.  However, nothing seemed to work.  (Imgur album for a better description of this)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/i78Og.jpg

Interesting data point, when I zoom into 200% on my screen (3200 x 1800 resolution), the problem disappears.  That made me think it was width-related, but the two things previous items didn't turn up solutions.

Finally, I found this Stack Overflow (question about a similar kind of offset problem,)[[Absolutely-positioned table header (th) - which browser is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973275/absolutely-positioned-table-header-th-which-browser-is-wrong/22032376#22032376]) but it seemed to relate only to the collapsing borders element.

My going theory is that it's some kind of similar rounding error related to Firefox, but nothing seems to change when I move the parent div's border element to 4px instead of 3 (that way it is even).

## **TL;DR**

To summarize this giant post, I'm getting inconsistent, half-pixel offsets in Firefox only.  Although I am looking for a solution in the end, I am much more interested in the "why" behind this.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the issue in Firefox 57.0.4

Comment: Hrmm, I'm also using Firefox 57.0.4.  May I ask what is your screen resolution?

Comment: I tried on both 1920x1080 and 2560x1440. Also tried various Windows scaling percentage options

Comment: Just recreated the issue by zooming in Firefox to 130% instead of 100%

Comment: Does setting height to 110px on the .game-result-spacer-red-active class fix the issue for you?

Comment: Yes it does, which might make you a saint. =D  Thank you!  Submit an answer and I'm happy to mark it, though still curious as to the "why."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate the issue by zooming Firefox in to 130% (and some other bigger sizes too)

Setting the `height` on both `.game-result-spacer-blue-active` and `.game-result-spacer-red-active` to `110px` seems to get things to line up.

Or you could change the `.team-result` class along with those other 2 to have a 100% height

Or just try something different to get the diagonal line appearance to work instead of using borders. I imagine Firefox calculates the scaling differently for divs and borders and somehow ends up being off because of this. I'm not completely sure of the ins and outs of what it's doing that causes this to happen though.

Comment: Ended up specifying the height in the spacer-triangles to 110px.  I think you're right in that it's how Firefox calculates the scaling differently.  My theory is that by giving the element a height of 0, I was stuck with an edge case implementation that differed in Firefox.  Now that I'm specifying a height, it's consistent behavior across browsers because a non-zero height is a lot more common use case.  Thanks for you help, @abney317!