# Google Chrome CSS box model issue: box-sizing + table + 100% height + border

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-tables

Take a look at this fiddle (in Google Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/776uaj5b/1/

```
<div style="background-color: blue;">
        <table style="height: 100px;border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 100%;width: 100px;">
                    <div style="height: 100%;background-color: red;">
                        BOX1
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="height: 100%;width: 100px;">
                    <div style="height: 100%;background-color: red;border-width: 10px;border-color:green;border-style:solid;box-sizing: border-box;">
                        BOX2
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Why is the BOX2 pushed down by the amount of border of BOX1? Is this a bug?

In Firefox and even IE it looks normal.

Comment: It looks fine to me . . .

Comment: I will never get tired of seeing "it even works on IE", ever.

Comment: On a serious note, could this be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068909/why-is-box-sizing-acting-different-on-table-vs-div/19069129#19069129

Comment: for me BOX1 is pushed down by 1px, like as `td` has 1px padding. You can get rid of it by setting `padding: 0;` for `td`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `box-sizing` in the `div`. Keep in mind that `box-sizing` is experimental technology. One solution i find* is to use `box-sizing: border-box;webkit-box-sizing: content-box;` and remove it from the inline style in div(also please try to avoid inline styles):

```
div {
   box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/3npqf6xo/)

**Reference**

[MDN box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

*with @BoltClock's help :)

Comment: Given that there's no corresponding `-ms-box-sizing` property, it may be a better idea to set `box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box` instead. As long as Chrome continues to support the prefix anyway.