# border-box adding 1px space on top and bottom of a <a> block

Tags: css

I need some help figuring out where a 1px space on top and bottom of a `<a>` inside a td comes from, and how to remove it.

The `<a>` is displayed as a flexbox, which is required, and fills the entire td.
It seems to be caused by `border-sizing: border-box` but I don't understand why (if you remove the property it works fine, but I kind of need it and would rather find another solution if a clean alternative exists).

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
 padding: 0;
}

td {
 width: 5rem;
 height: 5rem;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 outline: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just in Chrome, btw, Firefox and (even! IE 11) display is ok.

Comment: Try it in different browsers. It seems like different browsers count the border either inside or outside the border-box.

Comment: @sinisake, do you have a fix to make all browser behave the same way?

Comment: Sort of.... https://jsfiddle.net/1uce0xLd/1/ ?

Comment: @sinisake thank you for pointing this out, I was indeed using chrome. still gotta fix it tho :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19068909/483779

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately it's bad news for me !

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `box-sizing: border-box` to the `*` selector, and `box-sizing: content-box` to the `td > a` elements. Also, the `width: 100%` can be removed from the `a` element.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td > a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box; 
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However it seems to be working only because the property `* { box-sizing: border-box }` is removed from the css, which I need :/ I'm going to look into that !

Comment: Ok, then apply `box-sizing: border-box` to `*` and apply `box-sizing: content-box` to `td > a`. The solution has been updated above.