# Table is not well displayed in other browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` on my web page. On Google Chrome the `<table>` is well displayed. It has a padding on left and right. When I print the page it is well displayed also. It fits on paper. But when I try to open the page in Internet Explorer or Mozilla Firefox the `<table>` does not fit. There is no padding-right and the last column is displayed half. Also when I print the page the last column is printed half.

Does someone know how I can fix this problem?

Here is the CSS of my `<table>`

```
table.inventory { clear: both; border: 0px; line-height: 1.2;width: 100%; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;font-size: 85%;}
table.inventory th { font-weight: bold; border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: left; }

table.inventory td:nth-child(1) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;width: 47.5%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(2) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;width: 12.5%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(3) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: right; width: 15%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(4) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: right; width: 12.5%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(5) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: right; width: 12.5%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ss6780qn/

Comment: could you create example in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Could you show HTML with some rows?

Comment: Do you use bootstrap or something else?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ss6780qn/

Comment: As you see there is no padding on the right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068909/why-is-box-sizing-acting-different-on-table-vs-div

Comment: @Gerard do I need to write `box-sizing: border-box;` in the `<div>`?

Comment: If it is an option for you, use divs and display:table, display:table-cell. Apparently tables don't work well with box-sizing across browsers.

Comment: @Gerard. It worked. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set box-sizing from content-box to border-box in your global selector

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this into your CSS and then you can see padding-right and also last column.

```
body {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Add the above code.

```css
*
{
 border: 0;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 font-weight: inherit;
 line-height: inherit;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 vertical-align: top;
}

body {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* page */

html { font: 16px/1 'Arial', sans-serif; overflow: auto; padding: 0.5in; }
html { background: #999; cursor: default; }

body { box-sizing: border-box; height: 11in; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 0.3in; width: 8.5in; }
body { background: #FFF; border-radius: 1px; box-shadow: 0 0 1in -0.25in rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

table.inventory { clear: both; border: 0px; line-height: 1.2;width: 100%; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;font-size: 85%;}
table.inventory th { font-weight: bold; border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: left; }

table.inventory td:nth-child(1) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;width: 47.5%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(2) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;width: 12.5%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(3) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: right; width: 15%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(4) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: right; width: 12.5%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(5) { border: 0px;line-height: 1.2;text-align: right; width: 12.5%; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table class="inventory">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>COL1</span></th>
        <th><span>COL2</span></th>
        <th><span>COL3</span></th>
        <th><span>COL4</span></th>
        <th><span>COL5</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Test data 1</span></td>
        <td><span>Test data 1</span></td>
        <td><span>Test data 1</span></td>
        <td><span>Test data 1</span></td>
        <td><span>Test data 1</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still the same. In Google Chrome there is a `padding-left:20px;` and `padding-right:20px;`. In Internet Explorer and Firefox there is a `padding-left:20px;` but `padding-right` looks like `padding-right:5px;`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not having IE right now. But, I have checked in mozilla firefox. It looks fine to me. I'm giving you link below. You can check there. The same code in JSfiddle as in above snippet.
https://jsfiddle.net/Dhruvil21_04/ng2LqaLx/